# How can I recover transformation that was applied in the DataLoader?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, torchvision

We define some some `DataSet` with some randomized `transform`s that will be reapplied each time some particular image is loaded. Is it possible to also extract the transformation that was applied to the image with the image?
(I'd like to apply the transformation that was applied to the image to some other image too.)

```
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.utils.data

path = "/path/to/image/folders/" #should contain at least one folder with some images
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
    transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=[0, 360]),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])
dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=path, transform=transform)

dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=dataset, shuffle=True)

for input, target in dataloader:
    pass #get transform that was applied to input?
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an API to get the applied transforms.

Can you just reimplement `__call__` methods of the randomized transforms so they also log what was applied? (it's just couple of lines: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/transforms/transforms.html#RandomHorizontalFlip)